# Finding all Nullable Columns in SQL 2000 Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, constraints

How to find out column with NULL values allowed in the insert in whole database ?

Comment: You may / may not also wish to exclude the ones that can't be made null b/c of a check constraint. which may lead to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195136/420667, Substring, and CharIndex can be used to get the column name from the definition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have sql at hand, but the query goes something like this

```
  SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE is_nullable = 'YES'
```

In general, search for this stardard view, for all the metadata info about your schema and structure of the database; there are many others (information_schema.tables, information_schema.constraints, etc)

Comment: Probably should be is_nullable = 'YES' (caps) to avoid issues if your database is set to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Those who only want to see columns from base tables (not views) should join with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.  I also like to exclude the system table `sysdiagrams`.

**Query**

```
SELECT
     c.TABLE_NAME,
     COLUMN_NAME,
     DATA_TYPE
FROM
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
     JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE
     is_nullable = 'YES' AND
     TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND
     c.TABLE_NAME != 'sysdiagrams'
ORDER BY
     c.TABLE_NAME,
     COLUMN_NAME
```

If you have duplicate table names across schemas or table catalogs, you should involve those fields in the join as well, as shown in the answers here:

[Differentiating tables and views in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7647/114621).