# How to see contents of Check Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a TSQL script that will allow me to see the contents of a constraint. I found a question regarding Oracle but I need a TSQL script.

[How to see contents of Check Constraint on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686353/how-to-see-contents-of-check-constraint-on-oracle)

I am aware of sys.check_constraints, however, the 'definition' comes back null for all objects.

```
Select * from sys.check_constraints
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another way

for check constraints

```
select definition,name
 from sys.check_constraints
```

for default constraints

```
select definition,name
 from sys.default_constraints
```

and yet another way

```
 SELECT object_definition(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_NAME)),* 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
 where CONSTRAINT_TYPE <> 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Comment: Might be a permission issue, if your login doesn't have sufficient privileges you won't see it

Comment: It was a permission issue. Unfortunately, I'll have to bug the DBA everytime I encounter constraint errors.

Comment: Note: ***sys.check_constraints*** for check constraints on columns, not valid for _check constraints on tables_. Eg: `CONSTRAINT CK_NumeroUsadas_NumeroTotal CHECK (NumeroUsadas <= NumeroTotal AND NumeroTotal >= 0),`

Comment: Note: `SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME,CHECK_CLAUSE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` for search content in constraint, and `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'CHECK'` for get all constraints (***CHECK***)

Comment: Note: ***Search for text inside a constraint:*** 
1.) `SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME,CHECK_CLAUSE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE CHECK_CLAUSE like  '%NumeroTotal%' or CHECK_CLAUSE LIKE '%NumeroUsadas%'`
and 2.) `SELECT object_definition(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_NAME)),* 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS  WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'CHECK'
 AND  object_definition(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_NAME)) like  '%NumeroTotal%' 
 or  object_definition(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_NAME)) LIKE '%NumeroUsadas%'`

Comment: @SQLMenace to see definition user must have minimum read definition permission on SQL server. Otherwise, it returns null

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

Comment: Note: `SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME,CHECK_CLAUSE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` for search content in constraint, and `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'CHECK'` for get all constraints (***CHECK***)

Answer (score 3):

> sys.default_constraints for default constraints on columns
>
> sys.check_constraints for check constraints on columns
>
> sys.key_constraints for key constraints (e.g. primary keys)
>
> sys.foreign_keys for foreign key relations

***sys.check_constraints*** for check constraints on columns, not valid for check constraints on tables. Eg: `CONSTRAINT CK_NumeroUsadas_NumeroTotal CHECK (NumeroUsadas <= NumeroTotal AND NumeroTotal >= 0),`

***Search for text inside a constraint:***

1.) `SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME,CHECK_CLAUSE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE CHECK_CLAUSE like  '%NumeroTotal%' or CHECK_CLAUSE LIKE '%NumeroUsadas%'`

2.) `SELECT object_definition(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_NAME)),* 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS  WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'CHECK'
 AND  object_definition(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_NAME)) like  '%NumeroTotal%' 
 or  object_definition(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_NAME)) LIKE '%NumeroUsadas%'`

Answer (score 1):

To have any check constraints, you're going to need objects of this type.

```
select *
from sys.objects
where sys.objects.type = 'C'
```

[check_constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187388.aspx)